# MS Excel, detect errors in a sequential list of numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm having to proofread photo logs in Excel, and would like to find a way to check for gaps in the numbers. The photo numbers are listed in a column with entries like:

```
1
2-5
6
7-21
22-98
99-142
143-219
220
221
222-343
```

etc.

Is there any easy way to detect gaps or duplicate entries in the sequence?

like:

```
2-5
5
6-9
```

this has a duplicate 5

or:

```
2-5
7
8-9
```

this has a gap between 5 and 7

Thanks for any advice! Checking these by hand is a pain.

Answer (score 1):

### Detect Missing and Duplicates in a Sequential List

```
=LET(data,A2:A8,delimiter,"-",mis,"Missing",dup,"Dupes",
    s,DROP(REDUCE("",data,LAMBDA(rr,r,LET(
        t,--TEXTSPLIT(r,,delimiter),
        tr,IF(ROWS(t)=1,t,LET(
            fs,INDEX(t,1,1),
            ss,INDEX(t,2,1),
            IF(fs>ss,SEQUENCE(fs-ss+1,,fs,-1),
                SEQUENCE(ss-fs+1,,fs)))),
        IFERROR(VSTACK(rr,tr),rr)))),1),
    ss,SORT(s),
    ts,SEQUENCE(MAX(ss)-MIN(ss)+1,,MIN(ss)),
    fm,FILTER(ts,ISNA(INDEX(ts,XMATCH(ts,ss)))),
    fd,FILTER(ss,ss=VSTACK(0,DROP(ss,-1)),""),
    result,VSTACK(HSTACK(mis,dup),IFNA(HSTACK(fm,fd),"")),
    result)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, very thorough error checking!

Comment: Thank you for the code, but it is throwing #CALC! errors whenever there is not any missing or duplicated entries (i.e. the data has no errors) and it is also not recognizing some errors in cells with a single number. For example, in the data set: 1 / 2-8 / 8 / 9-10  it does not recognize the duplicated 8. 

Thank you though, it is much better than any solution I've come up with!